# Can't bind property to radio group in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, angular5

I want to change action, that will be applied to file, using radio button group (Bootstrap 4). Action is stored in the `fileRecord`'s `action` field. When I choose something, text in `<h4>{{record.action}}</h4>` is not being changed, it displays initial value.
Using Angular 5.2.8.
What I'm doing wrong?

[image: 'Do not touch' (=='skip' action) is chosen, but 'remove' is displayed]

upgrade.component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of fileRecords; index as i">
  <th scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
  <td>{{record.pathName}}</td>
  <td [ngClass]="{'table-primary' : record.proposedAction=='skip',
        'table-warning' : record.proposedAction=='upgrade',
        'table-danger' : record.proposedAction=='remove'}">{{record.proposedAction}}</td>
  <td>
    <div class="btn-group form-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-warning">
        <input type="radio" name="record.pathName +'_action'" autocomplete="off" value="upgrade" [(ngModel)]="record.action" />Upgrade
      </label>

      <label class="btn btn-outline-danger">
        <input type="radio" name="record.pathName +'_action'" autocomplete="off" value="remove" [(ngModel)]="record.action" />Remove
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="record.pathName +'_action'" autocomplete="off" value="skip" [(ngModel)]="record.action" />Do not touch
      </label>
    </div>
  <h4>{{record.action}}</h4>
  </td>
</tr>
```

upgrade.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { FileRecord } from "../../_models/fileRecord";
import { StorageService } from "../../_services/storage.service";

@Component({
  templateUrl: './sector-upgrade.component.html'
})
export class SectorUpgradeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private storageService: StorageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAvailableFolders();
  }

  availableFolders: string[];
  selectedFolder: string = null;

  @Input() fileRecords: FileRecord[];

  getAvailableFolders() {
    this.storageService.getAvailableFolders().subscribe( data => {
      if (data) {
        this.availableFolders = data as string[];
      }    
    } );
  }

  getUpgradeFiles(folder: string) {
    this.storageService.getUpgradeFiles(folder).subscribe( data => {
      if (data) {
        this.fileRecords = data as FileRecord[];
        this.fileRecords.forEach(fileRecord => {
          fileRecord.action = fileRecord.proposedAction;
        });
      }    
    } );
  }

  onSelectFolder(folder: string): void {
    if (folder != this.selectedFolder) {
      this.selectedFolder = folder;
      this.getUpgradeFiles(folder);
    }
  }    
}
```

**Update:**
Tried `[value]=` instead of `value=`, it has to effect and gives such warning in Visual Studio Code:

[image: Update]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in `data-toggle="buttons"`. It's provided by Bootstrap's JS that is in conflict with Angular.

To create and use such radio buttons now I use ng-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by using [value]="something" instead of value="something"